# Symfony layout in another folder

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

Is it possibile to put layout files in the modules/templates (or something else) directory instead of the general app/templates?

I've tried to put the path in `view.yml` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found a workaround so I can keep `layout.php` inside the module/templates folder:

```
public function preExecute()
{
    $template = $this->getContext()->getConfiguration()->getTemplateDir('MODULE', 'layout.php');
    $this->setLayout($template . '/layout');
}
```